# Get site url in ContentEditorWebPart content

Tags: site, content-editor-web-part, url

I have added a ContentEditorWebPart to an Element file in visual studio.  I want to get the current site url and place it in the content block (between the cewp:Content tags).

How would i do this?

Please note i am in a sandboxed solution so this is the only way i can add a ContentEditorWebPart.  How do i reference the current site url using the code below?

```
  AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="FullPage1" WebPartOrder="0"
    ![CDATA[
                WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2" xmlns:cewp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"
                AssemblyMicrosoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c/Assembly
                TypeNameMicrosoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart/TypeName
                TitleStructral Site Text/Title
                FrameTypeNone/FrameType
                cewp:Content
                  This is some content with a link. a href="http://mysite.com/mysubsite/"/a
                /cewp:Content
                /WebPart
                ]]
  /AllUsersWebPart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some js script and use the _spPageContextInfo object.

```
 This is some content with a link. <a id="siteUrl">click here</a>   
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.getElementById('siteUrl').setAttribute('href', _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
</script>
```